# I have broken my diamond pickaxe! Can I repair it somehow?

Tags: discussion, unicoins, april-fools, unicorns

While mining for unicoins, I found a **"diamond pickaxe +2"** in a chest under a rock. It was great! It broke all rocks (even obsidian ones) in just one swing.

[image]

Now, after one hour of intense mining, the pickaxe has broken. Does anypony have an idea if I can repair it somehow? I've hearded something about finding the legendary beacon slab in the Golden pot at the end of the Rainbow, but I wasn't able to reach it yet (level to low for the area).

Can anybody help me with this quest? I am a level 42 unicorn paladine (pure dps/healing build). I will wait at the Meta Tavern in Stack city for anyone who wants to join my party.

Comment: I'd think Hawkeye could shatter rocks without resorting to a pickaxe?

Comment: @Oded (Yep, but today the avatar should be a different one.... Cache or the propagate button don't working, I don't know).

Comment: Also, if I use Yorula I would end up cutting the whole plain with a single swing. I could use the knife in my necklace, but I left it in the apple bowl on my desk at home...

Comment: The dangers of being a pirate king, eh?

Comment: A new downvote. But it forgot to leave a comment reading "*Humbug!*" ;_;

Answer (score 3):

You have to take it to the holy tree under which the Buddha reached enlightenment and then sacrifice a goat on vishnus altar.

Don't forget to pray to the Abrahametic Goddess of Mining while doing so.

You will find the proper tree in the woods on the left.