# Which device would work better for mining unicoins?

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, unicoins, april-fools

I [found](https://www.dealnews.com/features/Samsung-Galaxy-S5-vs.-Galaxy-the-Unicorn-Which-Is-the-Better-Buy/1018326.html) this infographic on mobile devices, and needed help deciding which device would work better for mining unicoins. I know that the "Galaxy the Unicorn" runs Unicorn Linux, but I'm a little skeptical because it was released in 2003. Will expandable memory be a problem?

[image]
<sub>(source: [dlnws.com](http://s31.dlnws.com/files/Galaxy_Comparison_2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: hehe , this is good

Comment: A flying unicorn is an alicorn. (I have daughters. I'm not creepy. Not that creepy, anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227730/where-did-this-pet-unicorn-come-from), it appears that Galaxy the unicorn is already equipped to mine unicoins, and so would be the better choice.

Expandable memory is not a problem, as the very little memory is required for this task, and increased memory just makes the device realize how long it has been working without a break. A more important factor that the infographic leaves out is the durability. If you smash a Galaxy S5 against a rock repeatedly, it will likely break after just a few rocks. Galaxy the unicorn has a very strong, sharp horn, which will last much longer.

As for concern about the device being released in 2003, this is necessary to avoid child unicorn labor laws. If you were to purchase a more recent model and put it to use immediately, you could potentially be fined far more unicoins than you received from the mining efforts. The same applies to the carriers. Those children are now adults, and so can be put to work alongside the unicorns, equipped with [diamond pickaxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227680/), hammers, and other tools.